# Listview always producing same image

Tags: android, sqlite, android-layout, listview

I have a listview and I am generating data from sqlite with custom cursor adapter for it. I have two text field and one Imageview in the listview. The text fields are filled correctly but the imageview is always displaying same image

here is my code

```
public class DatabaseHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {
        public static final String DATABASE_NAME = "Food.db";
        public static final String BREAKFAST_TABLE = "breakfast_table";
        public static final String LUNCH_TABLE = "lunch_table";
        public static final String DINNER_TABLE = "dinner_table";
        public static final String SNACKS_TABLE = "snacks_table";
        public static final String TOTAL_TABLE = "total_table";
        public static final String RECEIVED_TABLE = "received_table";
        public static final String COL_1 = "ID";
        public static final String COL_2 = "NAME";
        public static final String COL_3 = "CAL";
        public static final String COL_4 = "IMAGE";
        public long result;
        private SQLiteDatabase db;


public DatabaseHelper(Context context) {
    super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, 2);
    db = getWritableDatabase();
}

@Override
public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
    db.execSQL("create table " + BREAKFAST_TABLE + " (ID INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT,NAME TEXT,CAL INTEGER)");
    db.execSQL("create table " + LUNCH_TABLE + " (ID INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT,NAME TEXT,CAL INTEGER)");
    db.execSQL("create table " + DINNER_TABLE + " (ID INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT,NAME TEXT,CAL INTEGER)");
    db.execSQL("create table " + SNACKS_TABLE + " (ID INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT,NAME TEXT,CAL INTEGER)");
    db.execSQL("create table " + TOTAL_TABLE + " (ID INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT,NAME TEXT,CAL INTEGER)");
    db.execSQL("create table " + RECEIVED_TABLE + " (_id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT,NAME TEXT,CAL INTEGER,IMAGE BLOB)");




}

@Override
public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
    db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + BREAKFAST_TABLE);
    db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + LUNCH_TABLE);
    db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + DINNER_TABLE);
    db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + SNACKS_TABLE);
    this.onCreate(db);
}



        public Integer deleteData(String name,String tableName){
            SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
            return db.delete(tableName, "NAME = ?" ,new String[] {name});
        }


public void insertData(Food food,String tableName) {
    ContentValues contentValues = new ContentValues();
    contentValues.put(COL_2, food.getName());
    contentValues.put(COL_3, food.getCal());
    contentValues.put(COL_4,food.getImage());
    food.setId(db.insert(tableName, null, contentValues));

}
        public void insertDataToTotal(Food food) {
            ContentValues contentValues = new ContentValues();
            contentValues.put(COL_2, food.getName());
            contentValues.put(COL_3, food.getCal());


            food.setId(db.insert(TOTAL_TABLE, null, contentValues));

        }

        public ArrayList<Food> getAllFood(String tableName) {
            SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();
            ArrayList<Food> listItems = new ArrayList<Food>();


            Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery("SELECT * from " + tableName,
                    new String[] {});

            if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
                do {
                    Food food = new Food(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(COL_2)),cursor.getInt(cursor.getColumnIndex(COL_3)));
                    listItems.add(food);
                } while (cursor.moveToNext());
            }

            cursor.close();

            return listItems;
        }


        public Cursor getCursor(){
            String selectQuery = "SELECT * FROM received_table ORDER BY name";
            Cursor c = db.rawQuery(selectQuery, null);
            return c;
        }

        public ArrayList<Food> getAllContacts() {
            ArrayList<Food> foodList = new ArrayList<Food>();

            String selectQuery = "SELECT * FROM received_table ORDER BY name";

            SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
            Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(selectQuery, null);

            if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
                do {
                    Food food = new Food();
                    food.setName(cursor.getString(1));
                    food.setCal(cursor.getInt(2));
                    food.setImage(cursor.getBlob(3));

                    foodList.add(food);
                } while (cursor.moveToNext());
            }
            db.close();

            return foodList;}}








public class ReceivedItems extends AppCompatActivity {
ListView receivedMenu;
DatabaseHelper myDb;
Adapter itemAdapter;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_recieved_items);
    Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

    myDb = new DatabaseHelper(this);


    itemAdapter = new Adapter(this,myDb.getCursor());
    receivedMenu = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.receivedMenu);
    receivedMenu.setAdapter(itemAdapter);}}








class Adapter extends CursorAdapter {
private LayoutInflater mLayoutInflater;
private Context mContext;
public Adapter(Context context, Cursor c) {
    super(context, c);
    mContext = context;
    mLayoutInflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
}

@Override
public View newView(Context context, Cursor cursor, ViewGroup parent) {
    View v = mLayoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.received_list, parent, false);
    return v;
}

@Override
public void bindView(View view, Context context, Cursor cursor) {
    TextView txtName=(TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.receivedName);
    TextView txtCal=(TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.recCal);
    ImageView image = (ImageView)view.findViewById(R.id.recievedIcon);

    txtName.setText(cursor.getString(1));
    txtCal.setText(cursor.getString(2));

    ByteArrayInputStream imageStream = new ByteArrayInputStream(cursor.getBlob(3));
    Bitmap theImage = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(imageStream);
    image.setImageBitmap(theImage);}}
```

edit:[here is a sample from my received table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CItAw.jpg)

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="horizontal"
android:textAlignment="viewEnd">

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/recievedIcon"
    android:layout_width="60dp"
    android:layout_height="60dp"
    android:padding="5dp" />

<LinearLayout android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/receivedName"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
        android:textColor="#33CC33"
        android:paddingBottom="5dp"
        android:layout_weight="0.5" />
</LinearLayout>

<TextView
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
    android:textColor="#33CC33"
    android:textAlignment="viewEnd"
    android:id="@+id/recCal"
    android:paddingBottom="5dp"
    android:layout_weight="0.5" />
```

Comment: Are you sure you're creating and inserting the `Food` objects correctly?

Comment: I am receiving the food object by broadcast and I am putting it to sqlite and I checked my database with sqlitemanager. it was true @MikeM.

Comment: Well, you'll have to start debugging to figure out exactly where it is that the image doesn't change from one item to the next.

Comment: My first app is sending random Food broadcast in every 60 seconds. And I will display them in a listview. Name and calorie texts are filled correctly but, imageview always displaying a one image which belongs to Toast :)  I can put an image if you want  @MikeM.

Comment: That's OK. I know what toast looks like. :-) Are you absolutely sure the database's image blobs are all different? Are you sure the broadcasting app is sending a different image each time? It sounds like you've got several possible points of failure, and we can't really be certain where it's failing from just the code available here.

Comment: I just added an image please check it @MikeM. And the weirdest think is that even if I haven't got anyt Toast item in the table its still drawing Toast. But I am using getters for all of them. I mean if the image is wrong, Name and Calories also should be wrong, isn't it? But they are correct

Comment: This is a total guess, but it sounds like you've set the toast image as the background for the `ImageView` in the `received_list` layout, and the `Bitmap` decoding is failing in the `bindView()` method, so it's setting `null` as the image, but that doesn't affect the background, which would be why you still see the toast image. Check to see if `theImage` is `null` in `bindView()`.

Comment: I added received_list. @MikeM.

Comment: I dunno. Your first step should be to figure out where the toast image is coming from. It's clearly not in the layout you've posted, and it does look like all of the image blobs are different, so it's a complete mystery to me. I would suggest that you still debug to check if `theImage` is `null` in `bindView()` after the `decodeStream()` call. You should also compare those `Bitmap`s to make certain they're not the same image somehow.